# Can't decrease divs with jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to create div's dynamically. I'm able to increment the value and show up multiple div's, but when I decrease the input value, the number of div elements still increases. Can you help me please?

see here https://jsfiddle.net/alessiow/n9xskt28/199/ (edited)

```
    $(function() {
 $(".instancesN").change(function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    $(".instancesNContainer").empty();
    for (var i = 1; i < value; i++) {
      var block = $("<div>", {
        class: "block"
      });
      $(block).append($("div.instancesNSpecifics").html());
      $(".instancesNContainer").prepend(block);
    }
  });


 $(function() {
  $("input.usersvmaddnewdivsN").on('change', function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    $(".usersvmaddnewdivsNContainer").empty();
    for (var i = 1; i < value; i++) {
      var block = $("<div>", {
        class: "block"
      });
      $(block).append($("div.usersvmaddnewdivsNSpecifics").html());
      $(".usersvmaddnewdivsNContainer").append(block);
    }

  });
});
});
```

```html
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='number' min="1" oninput="validity.valid||(value='1');" value="1" name='instancesN[]' placeholder="Instances #" class="instancesN form-control" />
<div class="instancesNContainer"></div>
<div class='instancesNSpecifics'>
  <input type='number' min="1" oninput="validity.valid||(value='');" name='usersvmaddnewdivsN[]'  placeholder="Add new Users" class="form-control usersvmaddnewdivsN" />
  <div class="usersvmaddnewdivsNContainer"></div>
<div class='usersvmaddnewdivsNSpecifics'>


  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="col">
      <input type="text" class="form-control usernamevmN" name='usernamevmN[]' placeholder="VM-Username" />
      </div></div></div></div>
```

Comment: When you decrease the input , do you want to remove the div or what you are wishing to do when you decrese the number .

Comment: Can you be more specific , what kind of result you are wishing to have .

Comment: @PushprajsinhChudasama yes, I want to remove the div's (except the first one)

Comment: For example , when you give input of `2` , 2 `divs` should get added . and when you give input `-1` , one divs from bottom should removed ? Is it ?

Comment: When i give input 3, i add 3 more div elements. When i put 2, 1 div element is removed

Comment: @PushprajsinhChudasama input field counts the div elements. So if iI increment the number, div elements should increment (and this is happening).
When I decrement the number, div elements should decrement (and that's not)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has to do with where and how, you append the elements.

https://jsfiddle.net/chan_omega/mnh1gyjo/

```js
$(function() {

  $("input.usersvmaddnewdivsN").on('change', function() {
    var self = $(this);
    var container = self.closest(".instancesNSpecifics").find(".usersvmaddnewdivsNContainer");
    var value = self.val();
    container.empty();
    for (var i = 1; i < value; i++) {
      var block = $("<div>", {
        class: "block"
      });
      $(block).append($("div.usersvmaddnewdivsNSpecifics").html());
      container.append(block);
    }

  });
});
```

```css
.usersvmaddnewdivsNContainer:nth-child(1) {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="instancesNContainer"></div>
<div class='instancesNSpecifics'>
  <input type='number' min="1" oninput="validity.valid||(value='');" name='usersvmaddnewdivsN[]' placeholder="Add new Users" class="form-control usersvmaddnewdivsN" />
  <div class="usersvmaddnewdivsNContainer"></div>
  <div class='usersvmaddnewdivsNSpecifics'>


    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="col">
        <input type="text" class="form-control usernamevmN" name='usernamevmN[]' placeholder="VM-Username" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="instancesNContainer"></div>
<div class='instancesNSpecifics'>
  <input type='number' min="1" oninput="validity.valid||(value='');" name='usersvmaddnewdivsN[]' placeholder="Add new Users" class="form-control usersvmaddnewdivsN" />
  <div class="usersvmaddnewdivsNContainer"></div>
  <div class='usersvmaddnewdivsNSpecifics'>


    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="col">
        <input type="text" class="form-control usernamevmN" name='usernamevmN[]' placeholder="VM-Username" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice! And if I want to add multiple "Add new Users div's with different "Vm-Username" elements? See edited post please

Comment: @alessiow I updated my answer to work with multiple instances